# Why do I get unreachable code when attempting to perform 2nd data fetch in React Js?

Tags: reactjs, unreachable-code

I am currently new to React. What I am trying to do is to fetch data 2 times.
The first time is to fetch an array from server and it works.
The second time is to fetch data from the same server but on different route.
Here is my code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    //FIRST FETCH
    fetch("http://localhost:3000/currency").then( response => {
        if(!response.ok) {
            throw Error("Network Request Failed");
        }
        return response.json();
    }).then(data => {
        _currencyArray = data;
        this.setState({
            currencyArray: data, 
            currencyName1: data[0].name, 
            currencyName2: data[0].name
        })
    })  
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
    })

    //SECOND FETCH
    if(this.state.value !== 0) {
        fetch("http://localhost:3000/get_convert_value").then( responseConvertValue => {
            return responseConvertValue.json()
            console.log(responseConvertValue)
        }).then(responseConvertValue => {

        })  
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
    }
}
```

However, on the 2nd fetch, when I try to **console.log(responseConvertValue)**, I keep receiving '**unreachable code**' for this line, which make me unable to get date from this fetch.

I somehow have found out that this maybe due to the '**return**' I put at **return responseConvertValue.json()**, but if I cannot return that data, how can I get to next step?
What do I do wrong here?

I would be truly appreciate any help from you.
Thank you very much and truly sorry if you find this question is duplicated or ignorant.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't `then` argument (a function) supposed to have the instructions reversed?

```
console.log(responseConvertValue);    
return responseConvertValue.json();
```

(you write some data to the console and then return)